# conflict route in node js express

Tags: javascript, node.js, express, routes

I have an issue about my routes, i want to delete data form a page which contains blogs and comments,

I want to send a request to delete the comments with this script :

```
       trashcan.addEventListener('click', e => {
       const endpoint = `/admin/blog/details/${deleteBlog.dataset.doc}`;

       fetch(endpoint, {
           method: 'DELETE'
       })
       .then(response => {
           return response.json();
       })
       .then(data => window.location.href =  data.redirect)
       .catch(err => console.log(err))
   })
```

and

```
trashcan.addEventListener('click', e => {
  const endpoint = `/admin/blog/details/${deleteCom.dataset.doc}`;
fetch(endpoint, {
  method: 'DELETE'
})
.then(response => {
  return response.json();
})
.then(data => window.location.href =  data.redirect)
.catch(err => console.log(err))
})
```

but the route choose the blogs route,
even i renamed the url parameter id with different name, but always req.params stay the same .

the routes:

```
//delete blog
router.delete('/blog/details/:id', adminBlogController.blog_delete);
//delete comment
router.delete('/blog/details/:comment_id', adminBlogController.comment_delete)
```

I need a way to pass the specific id and check it in the route before handle the request so it can choose the matched route.

Comment: Those are the same route, and the first route encountered will match. You need some way to distinguish routes. Naming routes that modify different underlying resources the same thing is counter-intuitive. One modifies comments, one modifies blogs. Your client-side code should be a big clue that something is wrong—the URLs are identical except for the value of the parameter.

Comment: yeah true, even i changed the name of the parameter the req.params got the same value, i tried to use a different route and it's worked for me, thank you so much for your response and all these information <3

Answer (score 0, accepted):

please use different base routes for the delete

**Suggestions***

```js
//delete blog
router.delete('/blog/:id', adminBlogController.blog_delete);

//delete blogs's comment
router.delete('/blog/:id/:comment_id', adminBlogController.comment_delete);
```

or make it a single controller and find a way to manipulate the controller to differentiate between **id** and **comment_id**

Comment: thank you, the suggestion worked with me as hell, i appreciate your help <3